# Create an Image from a VM using the python client

Tags: python, azure

Using the CLI, there is a simple command to [create am image from a VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az_image_create):

```
az image create \
--resource-group myResourceGroup \
--name myImage --source myVM
```

But I am having a hard time achieving the same thing with the Python client lib. The [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.operations.imagesoperations?view=azure-python#begin-create-or-update-resource-group-name--image-name--parameters----kwargs-) `begin_create_or_update` from `azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.operations.imagesoperations` seems to be the right one but misses the `source` parameter.

What is the correct approach?

Comment: There is a `source_virtual_machine` parameter here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.models.image?view=azure-python

Comment: Are you suggesting to provide an `Image` object as parameter to `begin_create_or_update`? How would I construct this object then? What is its `location`?

Comment: The location of the VM your creating an image from?

Comment: Yeah sure :) But is that the region? Like "Germany West Central"? Or the resource group? I just don't know what `location` means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of experimentation I got it working like this.

```
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group, instance_name)
compute_client.images.begin_create_or_update(resource_group, image_name,
        Image(location=vm.location, source_virtual_machine=SubResource(id=vm.id))).wait(120)
```

The trick was to provide the `Image` argument and within it the VM id as a `SubResource`.